# How to display image files stored in mongoDB when an action is performed

Tags: node.js, angularjs, file, mongoose, multer

I m building a form which accepts file as input (attchment) and display current attachments of a specific user.
As part of this, i am getting attachment data once my component is loaded.

```
base64,255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1,1,0,96,0,96,0,0,255,219,0,67,0,5,4,4,4,4,3,5,4,4,4,6,5,5,6,8,13,8,8,7,7,8,16,11,12,9,13,19,16,20,19,18,16,18,18,20,23,29,25,20,22,28,22,18,18,26,35,26,28,30,31,33,33,33,20,25,36,39,36,32,38,29,32,33,32,255,219,0
```

Data is getting displayed in the form above.
However same data is displyed as below format in my  database.

```
attachments
:
Binary('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAUEBAQEAwUEBAQGBQUGCA0ICAcHCBALDAkNExAUExIQEhIUFx0ZFBYcFhISGiMaHB4f...', 0)
```

I am able to display data in base64 format in client console.
How can i convert in to link, when clicked the image is viewed?

Route:

```
 app.get(
    apiConfig.config.apiVersion + "/get/attachments",

    bugController.getAttachmentsById
  );
```

Controller:

```
let getAttachmentsById = async (req, res) => {
  let tracker = await bugModel.findById(req.query.id);
  await tracker.populate("attachments").execPopulate();
  res.set("Content-type", "image/jpg");
  let apiResponse = response.generate(false, null, 200, tracker.attachments);
  res.send(apiResponse);
};
```

Client component:

```
  public getAttachments() {
    this.Http.getAttachments().subscribe((response) => {
      this.bufferAttach =
        'data:image/jpg;base64,' + response['data'][0]['attachments']['data'];
      this.base64attach = this.bufferAttach.toString('base64');
      console.log('ttchedDAta');
      console.log(this.base64attach);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that we cannot directly store images in DB, instead i have stored images in my DB using Multer and store the link in my DB. That would be more appropriate.